# Can I set condition to component selector Angular 2/4

Tags: angular

Is it possible to add condition for a compnente selector ?

For exmple if I have a  2 simple compnenets  :

**First:**

```
@Component({
             selector:'app-first'
             templateHtml: 'first.html;
            })
export class FirstComponent {
   check=false;
}
```

**Second:**

```
 @Component({
              selector:'app-second'
              templateHtml: 'second.html;
           })
```

Then ,on my first.html file I set this condition:

```
<div *ngIf="check">
 <app-second></app-second>
</div>
```

It's always load me any way the second component,can I avoid this ? and
why it's happens?I don't find anything about that issue.

Thank you.

Comment: please provide plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works, you can even do

```
<app-second *ngIf="check"></app-second>
```

Do you have any errors in your console ? because this should work perfectly.

Comment: there is a little syntax error in your code , can please replace `*ngif` by `*ngIf` :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your template per se. The problem is with your @Component decorator configuration.
Replace the templateHtml with templateUrl.
You can see [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Component)